# how to download a pdf file from an url in angular 5

Tags: angular5

I currently spend one day in this issue,still failed to download a file from an url in angular 5

```
leadGenSubmit() {

    return this.http.get('http://kmmc.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lesson2.pdf',
    {responseType:ResponseContentType.Blob}).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        console.log(blob);
        saveAs(blob, "testData.pdf");
    },
    err=>{
        console.log(err);
        }
    )
}
```

when I run above code it shows following error

```
ERROR TypeError: req.responseType.toLowerCase is not a function
    at Observable.eval [as _subscribe] (http.js:2187)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
```

how can I solve this issue.Can any one post the correct code to download a  pdf file from an url in angular 5?

Comment: is `responseType` meant to be a header? shouldnt it be `Accept`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you should define header and responseType like this:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/pdf');
return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' });
```

Comment: shows 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource' issue

Comment: @federer then thats a server issue as the server doesnt allow cors

Comment: Then the requested webserver does not allow CORS. if it is your backend service, you have to allow cross origin on your server

Comment: but it works when i specify the url in the 'href' attribute of a tag?

Comment: what works? you asked to download it, not display it

Comment: it works after enabled the cors,but how can i set my filename as the name of file to be download?

Comment: How do you get the headers when you use responseType: 'blob'?  My api is returning a file and in the content-disposition it has the filename I want to use.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my simple solution to open a PDF based on an ID in Angular :

In my **service**, I created this method :

```
public findById(id?: string): Observable<Blob> {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.basePath}/document/${id}`, {responseType: 'blob'});
}
```

Then in my **component**, I can do use this method (behind a button or whatever):

```
showDocument(documentId: string): void {
  this.yourSuperService.findById(documentId)
    .subscribe((blob: Blob): void => {
      const file = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      window.open(fileURL, '_blank', 'width=1000, height=800');
    });
}
```

Comment: Would `${this.basePath}/document/${id}` be neater ?

Comment: indeed, thanks @daveD

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/pdf');
return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob' as 'json' });
```

References:

- Discussion on [Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18586)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711749/angular-5-how-to-display-image-in-html-that-comes-as-output-from-a-http-post/52729222#52729222)